# run scalatest with separate jvm per suite

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatest

I would like to run test suites in parallel from sbt, but with each suite getting it's own dedicated jvm.
(in my project there is a single resource per jvm, and it can't be used from different threads in parallel)

this is my test setup:

```
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory
import org.scalatest.FunSuite

trait BaseTest extends FunSuite {

  test("test1") {
    println(f"process_id: ${ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean.getName} -  thread_id: ${Thread.currentThread.getId}")
    Thread.sleep(5000)
  }
}

class Test1 extends BaseTest
class Test2 extends BaseTest
class Test3 extends BaseTest
```

and these are the setting I tried in sbt:

```
logBuffered in Test := false //make the logs nicer

parallelExecution in Test := true
fork in Test := true
testForkedParallel in Test := true
concurrentRestrictions in Global := Seq(Tags.limit(Tags.ForkedTestGroup, 4), Tags.limit(Tags.Test, 4))
```

this is what is printed when I run the tests:

> process_id: 16676@host -  thread_id: 13
>   process_id: 16676@host -  thread_id: 14
>   process_id: 16676@host -  thread_id: 12

the tests run in different threads, but all in the same process.

I there a way to have each suite it's own jvm?

Answer (score 1):

It's the first time I've heard of setup. In general it is hard as all tools try to reuse JVM as much as possible to keep it warm.

You can do something like running:

```
sbt -no-colors --error "print test:definedTests"
```

to get the list of test suites. If I run it for one of my projects I could get something like:

```
chimneyJVM / Test / definedTests
        Vector(Test io.scalaland.chimney.PatcherSpec : subclass(true, utest.TestSuite), Test io.scalaland.chimney.PBTransformationSpec : subclass(true, utest.TestSuite), Test io.scalaland.chimney.DslSpec : subclass(true, utest.TestSuite), Test io.scalaland.chimney.DslFSpec : subclass(true, utest.TestSuite), Test io.scalaland.chimney.IssuesSpec : subclass(true, utest.TestSuite), Test io.scalaland.chimney.JavaBeansSpec : subclass(true, utest.TestSuite))
chimneyJS / Test / definedTests
        Vector(Test io.scalaland.chimney.PatcherSpec : subclass(true, utest.TestSuite), Test io.scalaland.chimney.PBTransformationSpec : subclass(true, utest.TestSuite), Test io.scalaland.chimney.DslSpec : subclass(true, utest.TestSuite), Test io.scalaland.chimney.DslFSpec : subclass(true, utest.TestSuite), Test io.scalaland.chimney.IssuesSpec : subclass(true, utest.TestSuite), Test io.scalaland.chimney.JavaBeansSpec : subclass(true, utest.TestSuite))
chimneyCatsJVM / Test / definedTests
        Vector(Test io.scalaland.chimney.cats.CatsValidatedSpec : subclass(true, utest.TestSuite))
chimneyCatsJS / Test / definedTests
        Vector(Test io.scalaland.chimney.cats.CatsValidatedSpec : subclass(true, utest.TestSuite))
Test / definedTests
        Vector()
```

This output could be parsed by something like AWK or Python script to get the list of test suites grouped by projects.

As a next step you could for each project suite run:

```
sbt $project/testOnly $suite
```

This would run each suite in a separate process.

HOWEVER, each of these processes would use the same locks on the file system to make sure that some other process won't pull rug from under it (reasonable), but - even if you run `test:compile` before to avoid synchronization on compilation - this would result in something as I can only think of as ineffective, fragile mess. Each process would allocate memory anew (and with large quantity of suites this would take a lot of memory), initialize everything, all of them would fight for access to the same resources, and all of them would have to warm JVM from scratch. I would bet that this setup would be slower than running suites sequentially in one JVM unless you had a really weird use case.

Comment: that's an interesting idea, I will try to run is as an sbt task instead of a script. and just to clarify my setup, all suites can run in the same jvm as long as the running is sequential. the problem is when running them in parallel. so I don't really need 1 jvm per suite, it could also be n separate instances, each running a batch of suites